# How to do proper many-to-one / one-to-many with TypeORM (example in the documentation does not work in my case)

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I've been wrestling for a while with TypeORM many-to-one / one-to-many. I followed documentation on this to the letter but it doesn't work. Working with postgresql, TS and type-graphql.

Here is the code (no imports and parts that are connected to the issue):
**Entity Grades**

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Grades extends BaseEntity {
    @Field()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.id)
    users: User[];

    [...]
}
```

**Entity User**

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @Field()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => Grades, (grades) => grades.users)
    grades: Grades;
}
```

So i have Grades that can have many Users and User that can have only one Grades. It is possible to create user, create grade and assign grade to user (it is stored in column gradesId). The problem starts when i try to join Grades with Users that are assigned to them:

**resolvers.ts:**

```
@Query(() => [Grades], { nullable: true })
    async grades(
    ): Promise<Grades[]>{
        return Grades.find({relations: ["users"]})
    };
```

when I ran the query I get:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined",
```

This is how it looks in pgcli

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Grades entity's relationship like below:

```js
@OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.grades)
users: User[];
```

Answer (score 0):

Came actually looking for an answer of a related problem myself and stumbled upon this question... not sure if this is everything that's missing but BOTH sides of the relationship aren't defined properly. they should reflect the 'column' on the other side of the relationship.

Since you have on the `Grade` side the column `users`,

and on the `User` side you (should) have a `grade` column (this makes more sense semantically, as will get 1 grade per user at most)

Now the decorators should be something like this:

```
// Grade entity
@OneToMany(()=> User, user => user.grade)
users: User[];
```

```
// User entity
@ManyToOne(()=> Grade, grade => grade.users)
grade: Grade;
```